# HTTP error body empty using NGINX as reverse proxy

Tags: express, http, nginx, axios, nginx-reverse-proxy

NGINX proxifies my Express NodeJS app.

While in my development environment I properly get error codes and error responses, in production I only get error codes without the error response.

However, when I run the failing request in PowerShell I do get an error response.

In production the API and the APP are on different subdomains:

- "api.domain.com" // the Express backend
- "app.domain.com" // A React app using axios

In development everything is hosted on the same domain.

HTTP/2XX requests work as expected.

Please find below the production NGINX conf (from available-sites) :

```
server {
    server_name api.domain.com;

    location / {

        if ($request_method = OPTIONS ) {
            add_header Content-Length 0;
            add_header Content-Type text/plain;
            add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' 'https://app.domain.com' always;
            add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials' 'true';
            add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Methods' 'GET, POST, PATCH, PUT,OPTIONS';
            add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Headers' 'DNT,X-CustomHeader,Keep-Alive,User-Agent,X-Requested-With,If-Modified-Since,Cache-Control,Content-Type, Accept, Origin';
            return 204;
        }

        add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' 'https://app.domain.com' always;
        add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials' 'true';
        add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Methods' 'GET, POST, PATCH, PUT,OPTIONS';
        add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Headers' 'DNT,X-CustomHeader,Keep-Alive,User-Agent,X-Requested-With,If-Modified-Since,Cache-Control,Content-Type, Accept, Origin';


        proxy_pass http://localhost:3008;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
    }

    listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/api.domain.com/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/api.domain.com/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot

}
server {
    if ($host = api.domain.com) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    } # managed by Certbot

    listen 80;
    server_name api.domain.com;
    return 404; # managed by Certbot

}
```

I've tested various header configuration without success, any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was missing the "always" flag for the following NGINX header:
add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials' 'true' always;